# updating webpack from version "^4.30.0" to "^5.16.0" I'm getting weird errors for path and process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a react project and I decided to upgrade the packages to their latest stable version. but I'm getting a lot of breaking error because changes are major.

but these two errors about `path` and `process` is weird. I've first got an error that said:

```
index.js:3 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'path'
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js:3)
    at Object../app/config/env/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Object../app/config/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../app/libs/apiConfig/apiInterface.js (main.bundle.js:138704)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
```

So I searched about it a bit and decided to install `path` which wasn't `installed` before and it worked fine. so I've just used `yarn add path` and now I'm not getting the above error but I'm getting this one:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/path/path.js (path.js:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../app/libs/apiConfig/apiInterface.js (main.bundle.js:138703)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../app/libs/apiConfig/index.js (main.bundle.js:138901)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../app/app.js (main.bundle.js:119851)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `path` is Node.js core module. This should not be in any frontend code. Adding a third party `path` should only be necessary, if you really known why you need it in your react code.

Comment: @madflow `webpack` is runned by `nodejs`

Comment: Where is the above error from ? The Browser or the Webpack build on the cli?

Comment: @madflow actually it comes from the browser but it's one of my `config` files